# migrating from jboss4.x to jboss5.x

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to migrate my my EAR file from jboss4.x to 5.1.0GA.. I have multiple WAR files and corresponding EJB3.0 JAR files.... When i deploy this EAR in jboss4.x it works fine... But when I try to deploy the same EAR file in jboss5.1.0 it shows some error in log as follows...

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: remote not bound
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:399)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:399)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:726)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
```

Can any one please give some idea to solve this problem?... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have look into the following.
1. What all things you are using from JBoss (JNDI, Connection Polling, caching).
Once you find that you need to resolve that on the newer version.
2. What all customization you have done in current jBoss startup process so that you can  do  the same on newer version.  This includes classpath and few libraries priorities.